# Flutter: Call a function when message received from websocket

Tags: flutter, websocket

I need to call a function to refresh the list of orders in my app.

> 

```
Stream broadcastStream;
final WebSocketChannel _channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(socketUrl);
 websocket() {
    broadcastStream = _channel.stream.asBroadcastStream();
    broadcastStream.listen((message) {
      print(message);
    }).onData((data) {
      getOrders();
    });
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    websocket();
  }
```

I tried this, but doesnot work. This is the first time I am working with websockets. Is there any other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution

```
StreamSubscription streamSub;
Stream stream;
@override
void initState() {
  stream = _channel.stream;
  streamSub = stream.listen((message) {
    print(message);
  });
  streamSub.onData((data) {
  // print(data);
  callFuntion(data);
});
```